# Oracle DB: any function to select all the database columns except for one (which is known)?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am using Oracle Database and I need to realize a query which retrieves all the values of a table record (for a specific WHERE condition), except for one which is known.

Imagine to have the following table:
[Sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFAnR.gif)

Where you do not want to retrieve the "Age" column, but where - in next releases of the software - the table could have more columns respect to the ones actually present.

Is there any command in Oracle which excludes a specific column (always known, as in the example "Age") and allows me to retrieve all the other values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can create a dynamic query using `all_tab_columns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make that particular column Invisible using following query:

```
alter table TABLE_NAME modify COLUMN_NAME INVISIBLE;
```

This will exclude that column from `select *` statement unless and until you specify that particular column in select clause like below:

```
select COLUMN_NAME from TABLE_NAME;
```

*From Your sample data:*

```
alter table SAMPLE_TABLE modify Age INVISIBLE;
```

`select * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE` will produce

[image]

`select FirstName, LastName, Address, City, Age from SAMPLE_TABLE` will produce:

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks first of all.  Is the column invisible to all the users?

Comment: @GGG Invisible to all sessions (all users). It is defined in table definition.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches

1)You can set column `UNUSED`.It won't be retrieved (and it wont be used) with the queries. This would be permanent. You can't get then column back, the only allowed op would be `DROP UNUSED COLUMNS.`

```
   ALTER TABLE sample_table SET UNUSED(age);
```

2)You can set column `INVISIBLE`, this is temporary. It won't be retrieved, unless you explicitly reference it in `SELECT` query.

```
   ALTER TABLE sample_table MODIFY age INVISIBLE; 
   // to change it back to VISIBLE
   ALTER TABLE sample_table MODIFY age VISIBLE;
```

3)Create `VIEW` without age column and then query view instead of querying `TABLE`.

```
 CREATE VIEW sample_table_view AS 
 SELECT first_name, last_name, address, city FROM sample_table;
```